# How to handle Bad Request to return custom Response object for PostRequest in Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: spring-boot

I am Trying to create Api which can accept POST Request.
But I want to handle Bad Request Also. 
My Json object will be like

```
JSON Object
{    
      "name": "tom"
      "description" : "he is scholar"
} 

JSON object with incorrect parameter
{  
      "name": "tom"
      "descr" : "he is scholar"

}
```

```
    @PostMapping("/questions")
    public question addQuestion(@RequestBody question theQuestion) {
        theQuestion.setId(0);
        try {
            thequestionService.save(theQuestion);

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new badRequestException("bad request");
        }
        return theQuestion;
    }
```

For Bad Request it is throwing spring Boot internel error.
But I want to send custom JSON object to back to client.

Response in case of failure 400 Bad Request.

```
{
  "status":"failed to query"
  "description" : " can be any thing"
}
```

Help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@JsonAlias`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation.

```
public class Question {

    @JsonAlias(value={"description", "descr"})
    private String description;

}
```

This annotation was added in Jackson 2.9. You might have to upgrade/override Jackson version.

> For Bad Request it is throwing spring Boot internel error.

You can also add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation to `Question` class. Doing this will not throw error for `descr` key in JSON, but will initialize `description` field in `Question` object as `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the Response. can you tell how can I send back custom JSON object as mentioned above back to client.